# Python serial communication causing high CPU Usage when baudrate is 1000000

Tags: python, cpu, pyserial

I am writing a script using pyserial to communicate with the capture card. The baud rate is 1000000. Now I can receive data normally, but the CPU usage is too high by more than 50%. The following is my main code. Is there any solution?

This is the serial initialization part.

```py
try:
        ser = serial.Serial(
            port = ser_port,
            baudrate=1000000,
            timeout=0.001
        )
        if ser.is_open:
            print("\033[32m [LOG]Serial is open\033[0m")
        else:
            print("\033[31m [ERROR]Serial not Open \033[0m")
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print("\033[31m [ERROR]Serial not Open | {}\033[0m".format(e))
```

This is my main loop for my script.

```py
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        data = ser.read(1)
        if len(data) > 0:
            CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[0:-1] = CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[1:]
            CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[-1:] = data
        
        if CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[-4:] == bytearray([0,0,0x80,0x7F]):
            CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[-1] = 0x77
            f_data = np.frombuffer(CmdPacket_Data_Buffer[:-4],dtype=np.dtype('<f4'))
            counter += 1
            # print(int(round(time.time() * 1000))-t0)# 2ms
            if counter % 5 == 0:
                counter = 0
                f_vec = fp_calib_mat[:,0]+fp_calib_mat[:,1]*f_data**2
                f_vec[f_vec<0] = 0
                fp_buffer[0] = np.sum(f_vec)
                print("\r"+buffer_name+"f_sum={}".format(fp_buffer[0]), end='')
                # print(int(round(time.time() * 1000))-t0)# 10ms
```

Comment: Not that this matters here, but your spacing for your code looks terribly inconsistent.

Comment: It would probably be much more efficient to use `.read_until()` to read your entire packet in one call, rather than dealing with individual bytes.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize what @jasonharper said: reading data one character at a time is *absolutely* causing significant CPU utilization. Read your data into buffer, and then parse the data in the buffer.

Comment: @larsks Thank you for your suggestion, but I still don’t understand how to do it. Should I open two threads to refresh the cache and read the cache respectively? Then what function should be used to refresh bytes to the cache? Is it readall? How should the reader quickly search to the end of the frame to extract the data packet?